ut swapping two disks between RAID 1 servers via hot-swap: How to avoid RAID failure?

I have two servers with identical configurations, each with 8 disks set up as RAID 1 pairs (disk #1 is mirrored with disk #2, disk #3 with disk #4, and so on). Both servers support hot-swap, meaning I can replace the disks without shutting down. I need to perform the following operation: swap two disks (#3 and #4) from the first server to the second server via hot-swap, and swap disks #3 and #4 from the second server to the first. It's important to note that the data on these disks is different.
Questions:
Will the RAID configurations on both servers fail after such a hot-swap disk replacement?
How can I correctly confirm the "Foreign" configuration on the new disks to avoid errors and prevent data loss on the other RAID pairs?
Is there a way for the RAID controller to automatically "recognize" these disks, or do I need to manually import/clear the "Foreign Configuration"?
What is the best sequence of steps to preserve the integrity of the remaining RAID arrays on each server after swapping the disks via hot-swap?
I would appreciate any advice on the optimal way to swap the disks and configure RAID without risking data loss!

Can you edit your question with more specifics about which RAID controller brands and types you have on both servers (assuming it's not actually software RAID)? And what operating system? Then, it's not really clear what you're asking. You need to swap arrays between servers?


I have two servers with identical configurations [...] swap two disks (#3 and #4) from the first server to the second server via hot-swap, and swap disks #3 and #4 from the second server to the first.

That seems entirely pointless as the servers are the same...

Will the RAID configurations on both servers fail after such a hot-swap disk replacement?

Most likely. A RAID controller stores a serial number on its disks and in its configuration. Foreign disks are detected as foreign. There may be a way to import them without data loss, but from my experience there's no guarantee. Have a good backup at hand.

Is there a way for the RAID controller to automatically "recognize" these disks

No.

or do I need to manually import/clear the "Foreign Configuration"?

Yes, import. Clear means wipe the disks.

What is the best sequence of steps to preserve the integrity of the remaining RAID arrays on each server after swapping the disks via hot-swap?

Depends on the controller and its implementation - check the manual.
